# ESLint require curly brackets unless *actually* returning a value

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tslint, typescript-eslint

I've been searching for a way to configure eslint (or tslint) to require curly brackets on arrow functions *unless* we are using the implicit return. I've been looking at the [`arrow-body-style`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style) rule which gets us more in line with our desired standard than we currently have, but I'm not seeing a way to disallow a single expression arrow function *except* when there is actually a return value (*even if that return is specified as `void`*).

```
/* valid */
const example = () => ({ foo: 'bar' });
const example2 = () => {
  return { foo: 'bar' }
};
/*
 If there is a rule that covers everything but example3 below I'd be stoked as 
 I don't personally care if the team uses this or not!
*/
const example3 = () => void someFunc(); 
const example4 = () => {
  someFunc();
}

/* invalid */
const example5 = () => someFunc();
```

Does a rule like this exist currently?

Comment: Probably not. After all, though, there's always a return value - implicitly `undefined`...

Comment: Right, this is the scenario I'm hoping the linter can handle!

Comment: If you're using Typescript, let it handle it?

Comment: whatever someFunc returns will be the return value, even if it's void .. i don't see the reason to lint this at all

Comment: I've not found anything there either. This is completely a style preference we'd like to enforce. Bad code related to this isn't slipping through! I did throw a few of the examples into an AST Explorer and there are differences enough that it *should* be possible! With that said I've never written an extension so that would be fun :) https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/06896e3b78763f56b745abbf1c334879/4d924c51371d8f61682e48e2eda357b0487b830e

Comment: @JulianKleine that's where dev preferences kick in! Just to be clear, I understand all the differences and how they function. I'm just wanting to catch the instances where one of our devs is going fast and writes an arrow function that isn't inline with ourcode style guide!

Comment: @Jared thanks for the explanation, I understand.

Comment: Your "invalid" example doesn't seem any more invalid than your first valid example.  It's just `return someFunc();`

Comment: @MarkKahn right, I understand this isn't invalid JS.  However, it doesn't follow our internal code styles. For context, I hate the "nit" style PR comments and I would prefer to let the editor tell a dev when something should change.

Comment: Eh, I disagree with your styleguide then ;)  `const add5 = (x) => add(5, x)` is cleaner than a block with a return, but that's your call.  The eslint plugin implementation is like 2 lines: `arrowFunctionExpression(node) { if(!['BlockStatement', 'ObjectExpression'].includes(node.body.type) context.report(...) } }`